# Pyqt icon not showing selected

Tags: python, qt

I have written the following python program using pyqt4. It is a simple program to show icon in a window.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralWidget=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        w=QGridLayout()
        size=128
        icon=QIcon()
        mode=QIcon.Selected
        state=QIcon.Off
        pixma = QPixmap('a.png') 
        icon.addPixmap(pixma,mode,state)
        label=QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(size,mode,state))
        w.addWidget(label,0,0,0,1)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(w)
        self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint())
```

although mode is set to selected but I do not see the icon to be selected.
It shows me a selected icon when I write the code in the following way:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralWidget=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        w=QGridLayout()
        size=128
        icon=QIcon()
        mode=QIcon.Selected
        state=QIcon.Off
        pixma = QPixmap('a.png') 
        icon.addPixmap(pixma,mode,state)
        label=QLabel()
        #CHANGED CODE
        label.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(size,QIcon.Selected,state))
        w.addWidget(label,0,0,0,1)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(w)
        self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint())
```

what might be the issue?

Comment: There is no difference between the two examples.

Comment: But the two examples run differently as I said.

Comment: If u are asking where is the difference then I have highlighted the differece using a comment.

Comment: There is no real difference between the two examples, and running them produces exactly the same result (i.e. an icon in a window).

Comment: Do u get the same icon for both examples. I get different icons.

Comment: in first example I get normal icon and in the second one I get selected icon. Is this not the case with you?

Comment: No. You must be on a different platform. But in any case, you must be running different code to what is in your examples, because they are effectively identical: i.e. `print(mode is QIcon.Selected)` outputs `True`.